# Как создать список с огромным количеством чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Существует необходимость в создании спискa, где будет хранится числа от 1 до, скажем, 10000
Также не хочется использовать цикл
Идея в том, чтобы развернуть [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 10000] в нечто типо [1-10000]
Существует ли такое в python?
Написав

```
a = [1:10000]
```

Ничего не получилось

Comment: `a = [*range(1, 10001)]`. Но цикл в любом случае используется. Внутри функции `range`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
your_list = list(range(1, 10001))
```

```
your_list = [i for i in range(1, 10001))]
```

```
your_list = [*range(1, 10001)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант через python стиль "охвата",

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
>>> [ i for i in range(10) ]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```